# How to reproduce tor build using gitian?

Tags: git, tor, tor-browser-bundle

Please refer me to the steps to reproduce a tor build using gitian. I have been trying to build the tor browser bundle using steps mentioned at the following link-

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/BuildingWithGitian

But I keep getting errors, and I did not receive a reply from help@rt.torproject.org

> ~/tor-browser-build/gitian-builder/inputs
>   ~/tor-browser-build/gitian-builder/inputs object
>   ebcbfd6cdc29372909079d0345185733d47d90d4 type commit tag
>   tor-browser-38.2.0esr-5.0-1-build2 tagger Mike Perry
>    1439157725 -0700
>
> 5.0-build2. gpg: Signature made Sun 09 Aug 2015 06:02:10 PM EDT using RSA key ID D2F1E186 gpg: Good signature from "Mike Perry
>   " gpg:                 aka "Mike Perry
>   (Regular use key) " gpg:                 aka
>   "Mike Perry (Regular use key) " gpg:
>   aka "Mike Perry " gpg: Note: This key has
>   expired! Primary key fingerprint: C963 C21D 6356 4E2B 10BB  335B 2984
>   6B3C 6836 86CC
>        Subkey fingerprint: CC69 3F6C D7AA 6B8E EC40  EC28 4102 F895 D2F1 E186 error: could not verify the tag
>   'tor-browser-38.2.0esr-5.0-1-build2' tor-browser: verification of tag
>   tor-browser-38.2.0esr-5.0-1-build2 against
>   /home/tor/tor-browser-build/tor-browser-bundle/gitian/gpg/torbutton.gpg
>   failed!
>
> You should run 'make prep' to ensure your inputs are up to date make:
>   *** [build] Error 1

I ran 'make prep' and then 'make' but I still get the same error.

Edit:

After manually updating the key, but error still not resolved.

```
tor@tor-VirtualBox:~$ gpg -k
/home/tor/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------
pub   8192R/683686CC 2013-09-11
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@endarken.info>
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@unencrypted.info>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@fscked.org>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@torproject.org>
sub   4096R/0F129402 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]
sub   4096R/ACC0A961 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]

tor@tor-VirtualBox:~$ gpg --fingerprint 683686CC
pub   8192R/683686CC 2013-09-11
      Key fingerprint = C963 C21D 6356 4E2B 10BB  335B 2984 6B3C 6836 86CC
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@endarken.info>
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@unencrypted.info>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@fscked.org>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@torproject.org>
sub   4096R/0F129402 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]
sub   4096R/ACC0A961 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're doing anything wrong.  It's failing because you're using an expired `gpg` key for Mike Perry.  It's probably that the script doesn't understand what caused the error, so it asks for `make prep`.

Appears Mike uses a fixed main key but gives his subkeys and expiration time of 1 year and replaces them.  Amusingly [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en) Tor Project pages get it wrong too.

Just download his new key [here](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x29846B3C683686CC) and `gpg --import` it.  Or simply run :

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv 29846b3c683686cc
```

After that, running `gpg --fingerprint 683686CC` should show :

```
pub   8192R/683686CC 2013-09-11
      Key fingerprint = C963 C21D 6356 4E2B 10BB  335B 2984 6B3C 6836 86CC
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@endarken.info>
uid                  Mike Perry <mikeperry@unencrypted.info>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@fscked.org>
uid                  Mike Perry (Regular use key) <mikeperry@torproject.org>
sub   4096R/0F129402 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]
sub   4096R/ACC0A961 2015-09-07 [expires: 2016-09-11]
```

You'll notice the new keys now expire in 2016.

You can trust this new key really belongs to Mike Perry because it's actually the same base key with the same fingerprint.  It's only the subkey's that changed.  In fact, there is a good chance Mike does this precisely so that (a) scripts can update his key but (b) if his key is compromised then people cannot use the compromised key for more than 1 year, and (c) he'd keep the main key air gapped probably too.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I called `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv 29846b3c683686cc` in the tor-browser-bundle/gitian directory.

Comment: Is your system clock right?  I'd no key for him before importing it, but now if I run  `gpg --fingerprint 683686CC` then I get a key that expires 2016-09-11.  I donno if maybe removing his key first changes how `gpg` imports the new one, but that's surprise me.

Comment: There is no force import option, but try import by copying that webpage and using just `gpg --import` maybe.  I donno.

Comment: Just fyi, it should not matter what directory you do the gpg import in, as it adds the key to `~/.gnupg`, but you do need to import as the same user you build as.  It's possible these gitian scripts are using another key ring someplace, but that'd be odd as it sounds insecure.

Comment: Yes, I get a new key and `gpg --fingerprint 683686CC` shows a key that expires in 2016. Also, my system clock shows the correct date/time and I am using the same user for everything, although `make` does ask for the sudo password for the same user which shouldn't make any difference. But the build script is not using the new key.

Comment: Do I need to delete the old key ? Where is it located ?

Comment: I don't think so, but try doing the manual import, maybe it's just lazy about downloading a key it already has or something.  And use `gpg -k` to figure out if it updated the key.